# Unable to draw a scatter chart with vue-charts

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

What I end up with is blank page and the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBasePixel' of undefined

and no chart on the page. i'm new to vue.js so might be totally use error but I tried to use mostly the demos from the vue-chartjs page. and chart.js page. It seems as somewhere I screwed up but can't see where. Some people report that chrome.  Any assistance with thiis would be appreciated. Trying to bring in a few streams of data..2 to be exact....

***CHARTS.JS***

```
import { Scatter, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Scatter,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
    // If you want to pass options please create a local options object
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
```

**Randomchart.vue***

```
<template>
  <div class="small">
    <scatter :chart-data="datacollection" :chart-options="options"></scatter>
    <button @click="fillData()">Randomize</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Scatter from '@/components/Chart1.js'

  export default {
    components: {
      Scatter
    },
    data () {
      return {
        datacollection: null,
        options: null
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.fillData()
    },
    methods: {
      fillData () {
          console.log("firing phiil");
        this.datacollection = {
            datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            xAxisID: 'x-axis-1',
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
            borderColor: 'rgba(47, 152, 208, 0.2)',
            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(47, 152, 208, 0.2)',
                            ],
            data: [{
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }]
        }, {
            label: 'My Second dataset',
            xAxisID: 'x-axis-1',
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 208, 0.2)',
            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(47, 152, 208, 0.2)',
                            ],
            data: [{
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }, {
                x: randomScalingFactor(),
                y: randomScalingFactor(),
            }]
        }]
    }
        console.log(this.datacollection);
      }

}
  }

 function randomScalingFactor () {
        return Math.round(Math.random(-100, 100));
    }
</script>

<style>
  .small {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin:  150px auto;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with extra datasets params `xAxisID` and `yAxisID`.

it seems they're not set correctly, so when vue-charts tries getting references to those DOM elements, it gets `undefined`, thus the error.

You should either remove those params, or add those elements (via options or manually)

[Here is a working version of the app](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-funpp)

PS: also, if you need to get a random number from the interval [-100, 100], you should use `Math.round(Math.random() * 200) - 100`. 
In your version, it always returns either 1, or 0 (because Math.random takes no parameters and always returns a value between 1 and 0)

Comment: So what doc told you they don’t exist?

Comment: @BostonMacOSX Looked around, haven't found explicit documentation on this. try checking Chart.js documentation directly since it's based on it, or even the source code. did my answer solve you problem?

Comment: it did however not sure how to add the options to this so  ican get the axis labels...identifiers....

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is the problem. The labels are specified in `this.datacollection.datasets`, every set has the `label` property

Comment: Those are data label. I was trying to use options to define the axis. I’ll code pen in a few

Comment: Alright, in any case, if the original question was solved (`Unable to draw...`) please mark this as an answer. As for the vue-charts API reference, it should be a separate question